# Can I go to Terminal 2 from Terminal 1 in Dubai International Airport?

Tags: dxb, airport-terminals

I am landing in Terminal 1 of Dubai International Airport (DXB). I want to take a bus to Terminal 2 to go to Abu Dhabi.

Is it possible to go to Terminal 2 from Terminal 1?

Comment: Welcome! :-) With "go to terminal 2" do you mean "walk"? I suggest you elaborate on this a bit. Makes it easier to answer.

Comment: What is your nationality, do you have a visa for Dubai (UAE) and what airlines are you flying with?

Comment: Also, why do you want to go to Abu Dhabi from T2? As far as I'm aware there are no flights, do you want a bus or taxi or something?

Answer (score 5):

Well, probably :

[EDIT]

The link doesn't mention anymore the Terminal 2.

There seem to be no more shuttle to Terminal 2.

[END EDIT]

http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/to-from-the-airport/by-bus

> Shuttle Bus between Terminals
>
> There is a free 24-hour shuttle bus service between Terminals 1, 2 and
>   3. Simply follow the signs or ask our May I Help You team.
>
> You can also use the Metro between Terminal 1 and Terminal 3.
>
> If you’re connecting flights, you will be automatically transferred as
>   part of your connection.

Comment: Notice I am not a member of the May I Help You team ;-)

Comment: The text on the website is currently changed to "There is a free 24-hour shuttle bus service between Terminals 1and 3.", and doesn't mention Terminal 2.

Answer (score 2):

As if September 2018 there was no free shuttle bus from terminal 1 to 2  or from  terminal 3 to 2.  There is a shuttle bus only for employees from 3 to 2.  Pure lunacy on the part of the Dubai airport authority.  Everyone says you have to take a taxi which is supposedly cheaper from 1 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

walk not allowed , and its will be very difficult and long journey, around airport only highways , and pedestrian not allowed to walk around better take taxi around 15$ or use public transport http://wojhati.rta.ae/dub/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2?language=en ( link will navigate u) but using bus u will pay around 5$

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused about this. Isn't there a free shuttle bus between the two terminals as per the link in the other answer? Is that shuttle bus not running anymore?

Comment: @drat The link no longer mentions Terminal 2.

Answer (score 1):

There is no free shuttle between terminal 1 and terminal 2.
If you take airport taxi, it would cost 42 AED.

Answer (score 1):

As of February 19th, 2019, the link provided above (http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/to-from-the-airport/by-bus) still indicates that there is a 24h free shuttle bus between Terminals 2 & 3.