# How do I transfer from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 at Dubai International Airport?

Tags: layovers, dxb, airport-terminals

I am traveling with connecting flight where I have two different tickets: from Kiev, transit Dubai, to Kigali, Rwanda.

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43979/can-i-go-to-terminal-2-from-terminal-1-in-dubai-international-airport , http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/is-it-possible-to-walk-between-all-three-terminals-in-dubai-airport-without-leav

Answer (score 1):

It's incredibly easy and well organized to transfer at dxb.

You have absolutely nothing to worry about. Everything is perfectly organized, and there are huge signs everywhere. You won't miss it. There will be vast numbers of people doing just what you are doing.

Even if you need to ask there are people everywhere to ask. (These are even these virtual cut-out humans you can ask - hard to explain until you see one!)

It's exactly like being in a huge shopping mall, except all the prices are mysteriously higher, and they have runways and aircraft.

In your particular case you take a **bus** between T1/T2. It is free and on the "airside".  (You do NOT actually "leave" the airport and go outside.) You will never be away from air-conditioning.

DXB is the epitome of the "big but well-organized" airport. You can't go wrong.

Comment: > In your particular case you take a bus between T1/T2. It is free and on the "airside"

Comment: What does it mean? If I have seperate tickets with different airline, can I still change terminal?